# i am not being able to import code from one file to another in python.I am working on sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext

I have started learning python online a few days ago and was doing fine until i came across importing module tutorial.They said you have to create two files in same directory in order to import from one another.I didn't get that..I mean every file I have created in sublime text using python have .py extension to it if that what it means.But still when I try to import a code it shows error.What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO community. It means the location of your both .py files should be the same folder. Example - All your .py files stored in D:\python_tutorials\

If the issue still exists, please provide the complete error message.

Comment: Please show us your exact file structure, the content (at least the imports) and how you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Place all your python files in the same directory before trying to import them.